# Unable to scroll listbox in wpf datagrid row details when IsDeferredScrollingEnabled is set to true

Tags: wpf, c#-4.0, rowdetails

I have a wpf datagrid with **IsDeferredScrollingEnabled** set to true. I have a listbox inside row details template. When I try to scroll the listbox by dragging its scrollbar, its not scrolling because of IsDeferredScrollingEnabled. Any thoughts would help??

Answer (score 0):

Got the answer.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/wpf/thread/f95f4727-5e84-48da-b153-973128292172